# Websphere fails on using reserved words in EL

Tags: jsf, websphere, el, jsf-1.2, websphere-8

I've got a JSF1.2 application which deploys fine on Tomcat6 and Tomcat7.
So far so good.

One of the pages contains the following property on a h:inputText:

```
 disabled="#{quoteFinance.quoteSaved or quoteRequest.quoteDisabled or setting.protected}"
```

This validates and works fine on aforementioned Tomcat servers.
However, websphere8 believes this is a problem and throws the following error:

```
 disabled="#{quoteFinance.quoteSaved or quoteRequest.quoteDisabled or setting.protected}" [protected] is not a valid Java identifier
at com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute.getValueExpression(TagAttribute.java:259)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentRule$ValueExpressionMetadata.applyMetadata(ComponentRule.java:69)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:36)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:76)

Cause:
javax.el.ELException: [protected] is not a valid Java identifier
at org.apache.el.parser.AstDotSuffix.setImage(AstDotSuffix.java:45)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.DotSuffix(ELParser.java:1067)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.ValueSuffix(ELParser.java:1033)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Value(ELParser.java:978)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Unary(ELParser.java:948)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Multiplication(ELParser.java:712)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Math(ELParser.java:632)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Compare(ELParser.java:444)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Equality(ELParser.java:338)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.And(ELParser.java:282)
```

I had a similar issue with `#{msg.continue}` which is perfectly fine, but because continue is a reserved word, WAS8 throws me an error.

- Why does websphere not accept this while the code is working perfectly?
- How can I resolve this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: This [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/org.icefaces/icefaces-facelets/1.8.1/com/sun/facelets/tag/TagAttribute.java#TagAttribute.getValueExpression%28com.sun.facelets.FaceletContext%2Cjava.lang.Class%29) might be of some help. It looks like the exception is thrown in the following call `f.createValueExpression(ctx,this.value, type)`. Where `f` is the `ExpressionFactory` implementation on Websphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Expression Language 2.2](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245) spec:

> An identifier is constrained to be a Java identifier - e.g., no `-`, no `/`, etc.

`protected` can't be used as an identifier in Java as it is reserved.

This restriction applied in EL 2.1 too, so it was likely a bug in your old platform's EL parser that this ever worked.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is as per [EL specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html). You need to rename the property name to something which isn't a Java literal, or you need to use the brace notation so that it can be referenced as `String`.

```html
#{setting['protected']}
```

and

```html
#{msg['continue']}
```

This should have failed in Tomcat 7 as well, perhaps you were using a rather old version of Tomcat 7. This was been "fixed" somewhere between 7.0.0 and 7.0.10. It's currently already at 7.0.28.

Comment: I will check back when returning to work. Update tomorrow on the version ;)

Comment: Confirmed. These expressions are allowed in Tomcat 6.0.32 while it throws an error in Tomcat 7.0.24.

Answer (score 1):

"protected" is a java reserved word too! just like "continue"

Comment: I know. I was just wondering why these statements work in Tomcat, WAS6, WAS7 and no longer in WAS8